# Should MQTT have one account per device?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, iot, azure-iot-hub, aws-iot

If the MQTT account is shared and fixed in the device, I am worried that the device will be cracked and the account will be leaked.

I am developing a linux embedded device, using MQTT communication, currently the MQTT account is in the configuration file.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with AWS IoT, but my understanding is that you should generate a separate X.509 Certificate for each device. They then use the certificate to authenticate, without having any 'AWS Account' credentials.

Comment: Single account should work. But just for additional security, you can create separate policies with different topic for each device. That will have a clean separation between device data along with security.

Comment: Is this an MQTT issue? Or is it an AWS or Azure issue? You wouldn't save your StackOverflow password on a post-it (or on a plain text file on your device), so don't do it for an IoT Device. Look into Hardware Security Modules and Trusted Platform Modules. I think the question in its current form is too broad and lacks details.

Comment: AWS or Azure is just the tag

Comment: x509 is a good choice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [John Rotenstein](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein) and [Rimuru Tempest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18328720/rimuru-tempest) posting your discussions as answer to help other community members.

> Make sure to have X.509 certificate for each device. use this
> certificate to authenticate. This will help you remove the dependency
> of account.